# Illegal string offset 'nombre'

Tags: php, json

Estoy haciendo una pequeña prueba con api rest y tengo un problema que puede parecer simple para muchos, pero a mi me está dando quebraderos de cabeza.

Realizando un *var_dump* de la siguiente consulta sql me aparece el siguiente error:

> Illegal string offset nombre

Tengo todos los campos igual en la **DB**, así que no sé cual puede ser el problema. Si alguien me pudiera ayudar se lo agradecería mucho.

Adjunto mi código:

> **PD:** No hacer caso al bloque comentado.

```
<?php

require_once './vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$db = new mysqli('localhost','root','','curso_angular4');

$app->get("/prueba",function() use($app,$db){
    echo "Hola mundo desde slim";
});

$app->post("/productos", function() use($app,$db){
    $json = $app->request->post('json');
    $data = json_encode($json,true);
  
    if(!isset($data['nombre'])){
        $data['nombre'] = null;
    }

    if(!isset($data['descripcion'])){
        $data['descripcion'] = null;
    }

    if(!isset($data['precio'])){
        $data['precio'] = null;
    }
    
    if(!isset($data['imagen'])){
        $data['imagen'] = null;
    }

    $query = "INSERT INTO productos VALUES(NULL,".
        "'{$data['nombre']}',".
        "'{$data['descripcion']}',".
        "'{$data['precio']}',".
        "'{$data['imagen']}'".
        ");";

    /*
    $insert = $db->query($query);

    $result = array(
        'status' => 'error',
        'code' => 404,
        'message' => 'Error al crear el producto'
    );

    if($insert){
        $result = array(
            'status' => 'success',
            'code' => 200,
            'message' => 'Producto creado correctamente'
        );
    }*/
    var_dump($data);    
   // var_dump($query);
});

$app->run();

?>
```

Comment: Me aparece el mismo error, por eso no sé como proceder

Comment: No te pregunte por el error, te pregunte por los valores de var_dump($data)

Comment: Haciendo el var_dump($data) me aparece lo siguiente: string(4) "null"

Comment: entonces tu query de sql esta mal.

Comment: Puede ser, pero ese var_dump lo hago después de declarar la variable, con el resto de código comentado, eso es en lo que estoy perdido

Comment: Si $data es null, $json igual debe ser null, por lo que $app tambien debe ser  null... podrías mostrar como estan cargadas todas estas con el var_dump ??

Comment: Como bien dices, todas esas variables dan lo mismo con var_dump(las he probado), null. Ya no sé lo que puede fallar porque no me coge ningún campo de la bd.